# Array of a specific size used out of the function it was initialized in

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm a high school student learning programming and I have a problem that I can't figure out how to solve.

I have an integer "x", and I want a matrix "mat" to have the size of "x":

```
int mat[x][x];
```

But that works only in `main()` where I've read `x`;

For example if `x == 5`, the equivalent would be

`int mat[5][5];`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int x;

int mat[x][x];

void f(int mat2[x][x])
{

}

int main()
{
    cin >> x;
    int m[x][x];
    f(m);
}
```

I've wrote this short program to show where it works and it doesn't work.

> error: array bound is not an integer constant before `']'` token

I've the error at the global declaration, at the declaration in function `void f`. It only compiles without errors in `main()`;

What can I do to create a matrix with the size of `x` outside of the main function?

Comment: You cannot do that, use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` and `resize()` instead.

Comment: Typically you do not want global variables as they make the code harder to reason.

Comment: `cin >> x; int m[x][x];` only works because of compiler extensions - it is **not** standard C++. In addition, you would need to [read a good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Programming by guessing is not the way to learn.

Comment: Size of  array must be a `const` which means you can't do what you intended. To allocate size dynamically at run time, use int pointer. If you want the size to grow and shirnk, use vector.

Comment: OP is clearly a newcomer to C++, but their question is pretty good, contains a [mcve], gives the specific error... +1

Comment: @YSC But, lacks research. Which is why I downvoted.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius Trust me, I did research, and all the answers said why the error shows, nobody said that you can't do that, and nobody asked if or how you can do that.

Comment: @CristiCristi _"Trust me, I did research ..."_ It's obvious you didn't.

Comment: C99 support variable-length arrays, btw...

Comment: @CristiCristi I, simply, don't believe that _all_ answers were like that. This topic (code execution flow) should be covered at the beginning of any, decent, C++ book, at the very least.

Comment: @moooeeeep Since C99 is C standard, and this question is tagged with C++, I fail to see how that would apply.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius To introduce a keyword that might help the OP researching the feature he is looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/1025391

Comment: When you want to create an array `x` must be known at compile time. That's not the case. Try with `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable length arrays aren't spported in standard c++. Besides you don't want the global definition.

What you can use portably in that case is `std::vector`:

```
void f(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& mat)
{

}

int main()
{
    cin >> x;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> m(x,std::vector<int>(x));
    f(m);
}
```

If you pass that vector around to functions or being allocated within functions, the size information will be kept at any time.

> What can I do to create a matrix with the size of x outside of the main function?

Something like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> foo() {
    cin >> x;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> m(x,std::vector<int>(x));
    return m;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat = foo();
}
```

Comment: This is clearly the right answer for the OP, but for more serious programming, you usually don't want a vector of vectors, but a simple class that allocates a single chunk of memory.  The caching behaviour is much better.

Comment: @Martin Totally use case specific if you need such optimization or not.

Comment: I think that typos like `std::std` are good enough reasons to introduce beginners to `auto` and `using`.

Comment: @Bob__ Fixed. THX for the hint.

Comment: A `vector<vector<int> >` is not far from a array of pointers and can be used the same. But it not a 2D array and you will find nowhere in memory a contiguous array of size `x*x`. IMHO, it is probably what OP needs here, but it should not be used if a true 2D array was required

Comment: @Serge Well, why bother about that here in 1st place?

Comment: Because SO intends to have high quality answers that serve as reference ;-). Arrays and pointers are misleading enough for beginners, so I think we should try to help them to identify possible pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

Handling of multi-dimension arrays in C++ is not easy. The best way to go is often to map a multi-dimensionnal indexing with a linear memory chunk.

For instance, for a 2 by 2 matrix, one can create an array of 2*2=4 elements and map it this way:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| map[0][0] | map[0][1] | map[1][0] | map[1][1] |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

This seems overly complicated at first glance, but it simplifies greatly the memory allocation.

For an arbitrary sized matrix of `width` by `height`, `map[i][j]` is at index `i*height + j`. This can be translated in C++, encapsulated in a template class `Matrix`:

```
#include <array>
template <typename T, size_t WIDTH, size_t HEIGHT>
class Matrix {
    std::array<T, WIDTH*HEIGHT> data;

public:    
    T& operator()(size_t i, size_t j) {
        return data[i*HEIGHT + j];
    }
    const T& operator()(size_t i, size_t j) const {
        return data[i*HEIGHT + j];
    }
};
```

This has the disadvantage that the `Matrix`' dimensions must be known at compile time (and can be mitigated, see note (ii) at end of answer). But it makes its use so easy:

```
void fill(Matrix<int, 2, 2>& m) {
    m(0,0) = 0;
    m(0,1) = 1;
    m(1,0) = 2;
    m(1,1) = 3;
}

int main() {
    Matrix<int, 2, 2> m;
    fill(m);
    std::cout << m(1,0) << "\n";
}
```

Note (i): Elements are indexed by `(line, column)` rather than `[line][column]` because we can't create an `operator[]` accepting multiple values.

[Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14216060b381a409)

Note (ii): This basic idea [can be enriched (demo)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc6278502bb9c11a) to handle resizable matrixes, with use of a `std::vector` instead of `std::array` and a proxy to `std::vector::resize()`.

Comment: If the dimensions are known at compile time, a plain array could be used couldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Variable-length array is supported by some compiler as an extension. The manual of the compiler provides more information.[Gnu VLR](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)

The storage duration of a variable-length array(if supported) generally can't be static, which is why you get the error message (global variables have static storage duration).

Unrelated: The major array bound of the parameter `mat2` isn't necessary, i.e. `void f(int mat2[x][x])` is equivalent to `void f(int mat2[][x])`.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has no provision for dynamic 2D matrix but provides all you need to create complex classes. A (static) 2D array is a contiguously allocated array of *height* arrays of *width* elements. Just mimic that and:

- allocate a linear array of width * height
- provide an `operator[](int)` that returns a pointer to the first element of ith row
- do necessary housekeeping in destructor and in a copy (and move if C++11 or above) constructor.

Example of code:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
    T *data;
    int width;
    int height;

public:
    // direct ctor
    Matrix(int h, int w): width(w), height(h) {
        data = new T[w * h];
    }

    //copy ctor
    Matrix(const Matrix& src): width(src.width), height(src.height) {
        data = new T[width * height];   // allocate and copy data array
        for (int i=0; i<width * height; i++) data[i] = src.data[i];
    }

    // move ctor
    Matrix(Matrix&& src): width(src.width), height(src.height) {
        data = src.data;  // steal original array in a move
        src.data = NULL;  // ensure no deletion will occur at src destruction
    }

    ~Matrix() {
        delete data;
        data = NULL;
    }

    // explicitely delete assignement operators
    Matrix& operator = (const Matrix&) = delete;
    Matrix& operator = (Matrix&&) = delete;

    T* operator[](int i) {
        //optionaly test 0 <= i < width
        return &data[i * width];
    }
};

int main()
{
    int w;
    std::cin >> x;
    Matrix<int> m(x, x);
    // you can then use m[i][j] as you would for a static 2D array
    ...
}
```

This class does not support any resizing *by design*. If you need that, you really should use a `vector<vector<T> >`. The downside is that it has no default ctor either, because the dimension must be given at definition time (even if we could easily imagine a 2 phases initialization...).

Comment: @Bob__: Oups, was even a compile error! Fixed. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score -1):

You can dynamic allocate memory to use, in the c/c++, it does not support dynamic size of static memory allocation, so, you just modify your code like this.

```
int x;
cin >>x;
int** mat = new int[x][x];
```

Comment: Why using `new` here? C++ provides any kind of containers and smart pointers to avoid that, since it's very error prone to use. Besides that your proposal won't work properly.

Comment: The container is easy to use. but, I think some one can operate the memory, it is good for to develop others, like big project. 
I just post example code..