# C++ Accessing a string in a vector in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I want to access the string in the first entry in the vector inside the first entry in another vector. My code:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> DatabaseRow;
std::vector<DatabaseRow*> data;

//getting data from database 
//(dont need this for this example)

//then print first entry out
printf("%s.\n",dbresult.data[0][0].c_str());
```

But then I get error:

> error: ‘class std::vector, std::allocator >,
>   std::allocator,
>   std::allocator > > >’ has no member named ‘c_str’

Any insight please?

Answer (score 6):

You are storing pointers to databases:

```
std::vector<DatabaseRow*> data;
                       ^ Pointer
```

So you will have to access it like:

```
(*dbresult.data[0])[0].c_str()

1. (*dbresult.data[0])  // Dereference the pointer
2. [0]                  // Access the internal Vector   
3. .c_str()             // Use the string
```

Or, do the better thing and don't make it a pointer, use it as an actual object the way it is supposed to be:

```
 std::vector<DatabaseRow> data;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution is working perfectly! I agree to rather not make it a pointer, but I am working on existing code base that I can't change.

Answer (score 3):

- `dbresult.data[0]`: this is a `std::vector<std::string>*`.
- `*dbresult.data[0]`: this is a `std::vector<std::string>`.
- `(*dbresult.data[0])[0]`: this is a `std::string`.

Here you go:

```
(*dbresult.data[0])[0]
```

---

But ask yourself:

- Am I sure I want to store pointers to vectors?
- Am I sure I want to have a 2D array instead of a nice [Matrix-like linearized array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42628050/5470596)?
- AM I sure I want to stick to C-like functions (`std::printf`) instead of the type-strong C++ equivalent (`std::cout` *et al.*)?